# Protoc Version 3.2 java files

Tags: maven, grpc, grpc-java

I have compiled my Protoc file using protoc 3.2 compiler. When i try to use it with maven dependency shown below, POM file is giving me error and all of the dependencies were not resolved. Wondering what is the right version of grpc-all i should be using that is compatible with Java code generated with protoc compiler 3.2.0

My pom file looks like:

```
<dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
  <plugins>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

Also, the error i am getting is, 
[image]

Comment: Please provide the error message for "but all the dependencies were not resolved."

Comment: Hi Eric, I edit the question and attached the screen shot for the error message i am getting. Looks to me it might be Maven exclusion issue as i have other project configured using 0.15.0 version of grpc-all jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out to be Maven issue,

Maven clean
Maven install fix that for me.